# How can I unregister this custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using a theme that has a Testimonials CPT that I don't need. I'm trying to unregister it but my code isn't working.

Here is the code from the theme that registers the CPT.

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

class Testimonial_CPT {

    protected $textdomain;
    protected $posts;
    protected $version;

    public function __construct( $textdomain )  {
        // Initialize variables
        global $wp_version;
        $this->version      = $wp_version;
        $this->textdomain   = $textdomain;
        $this->posts        = array();


        // Add the action hooks
        add_action( 'init', array( &$this, 'register_testimonials' ) ); // Register Associated Taxonomy

        if( $this->version >= 3.8 ) {
            add_action( 'admin_head', array( &$this, 'add_menu_icons_styles' ) ); // Add icon if WP =< 3.8
        }

        add_action( 'after_switch_theme', array( &$this, 'custom_flush_rules' ) );      // Flush rewrite rules
    }

    public function testimonial_init() {

        // Define the settings
        $settings = array(
            'labels'        => array(
                'name'                  => __( 'Testimonials', $this->textdomain),
                'menu_name'             => __( 'Testimonials', $this->textdomain),
                'singular_name'         => __( 'Testimonial', $this->textdomain),
                'all_items'             => __( 'All Testimonials', $this->textdomain),
                'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', $this->textdomain ),
                'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Testimonial', $this->textdomain ),
                'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Testimonial', $this->textdomain ),
                'new_item'              => __( 'New Testimonial', $this->textdomain ),
                'view_item'             => __( 'View Testimonial', $this->textdomain ),
                'search_items'          => __( 'Search Testimonials', $this->textdomain ),
                'not_found'             => __( 'No testimonials found', $this->textdomain ),
                'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No testimonials found in Trash', $this->textdomain )
            ),
            'public'                => true,
            'publicly_queryable'    => true,
            'show_ui'               => true,
            'show_in_menu'          => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus'     => false,
            'menu_position '        => null,
            'menu_icon'             => get_template_directory_uri(). '/images/user-icon.png',
            'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
            'hierarchical'          => false,
            'has_archive'           => true,
            'rewrite'               => array(
                'slug' => 'testimonial'
            )
        ); // End $settings

        // Conditional to set the icon if WP 3.8 <
        if( $this->version >= 3.8 ) {

            $settings['menu_icon'] = '';

        }

        // Store the settings in the post array
        $this->posts['testimonial'] = $settings;

    }

    public function register_testimonials() {
        // Loop through the registered posts
        // and register all posts stored in the array
        foreach( $this->posts as $key=>$value ) {
            register_post_type( $key, $value );
        }
    }

    public function add_menu_icons_styles() {
    ?>

        <style>
            #adminmenu .menu-icon-testimonial div.wp-menu-image:before { content: '\f110'; }
        </style>

    <?php
    }

    // Flush Rules
    public function custom_flush_rules(){

        //defines the post type so the rules can be flushed.
        $this->register_testimonials();

        //and flush the rules.
        flush_rewrite_rules();
    }

} // End Testimonial_CPT
?>
```

And here is the code I'm using to unregister it.

```
add_action('init','delete_post_type', 100);

function delete_post_type(){
  unregister_post_type( 'testimonials' );
}
```

I got the code directly from the WordPress Codex. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Remove testimonial CPT
 */
function remove_testimonial_cpt() {
    unregister_post_type( 'testimonial' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'remove_testimonial_cpt', 1000 );
```

Copy this code and paste it into your functions.php file of child themes

Important link:
[unregister_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_post_type/) we have a function to remove register CPT from websites